# GSM modem not responding 30sec (SMS app)

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, gsm

I've developed an SMS app (send/receive SMS using GSM modem) using this library - http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm

I have a timer that checks received messages every 3 seconds. 
The problem is that every few minutes I get this error:

```
***
at GsmComm.GsmCommunication.GsmPhone.GsmComm.GsmCommunication.IProtocol.ReceiveAnything(String pattern)
at GsmComm.GsmCommunication.GsmPhone.GsmComm.GsmCommunication.IProtocol.ReceiveMultiple()
at GsmComm.GsmCommunication.GsmPhone.GsmComm.GsmCommunication.IProtocol.ExecAndReceiveMultiple(String command)
at GsmComm.GsmCommunication.GsmPhone.ListMessages(PhoneMessageStatus status)
at GsmComm.GsmCommunication.GsmCommMain.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus status, String storage)
at SMS.BL.TimerCalls_rec.recProcessTimerEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Csharp\SMS GSM\SMS\BL\TimerCalls_rec.cs:line 57++++++++No data received from phone after waiting for 30000 ms.
```

This is the part of that code:

```
try
{
    // Read all SMS messages from the storage
    if (CommSetting.comm.IsConnected())
    {
        DecodedShortMessage[] messages = CommSetting.comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Phone);

        foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
        {
            ReadMessage(message.Data);

            //delete message
            indexP = message.Index;
            CommSetting.comm.DeleteMessage(indexP, PhoneStorageType.Phone);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    RIWL.log(err.StackTrace + "++++++++" + err.Message, "Error: ");
}
```

This is the line where the error occurs:

```
DecodedShortMessage[] messages = CommSetting.comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Phone);
```

Any ideas why once in a while the modem is not responding? 
Sending/receiving messages is done separately. 
While sending SMS - reading is halted and the other way around.

Can I do anything else to check if serial port is busy?

EDIT:
If it's any help, at the point when error happens, dllhost.exe - COM Surrogate appears shortly in processes.

Comment: foreach (ShortMessage msg in messages) ... SMSPDULib.SMS sms = new SMSPDULib.SMS(); ... SMSPDULib.SMS.Fetch(sms, ref message); ... phoneNo = sms.PhoneNumber;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modem is responding it's a bug in Mr. Scampers software. We've used the GSMComm software for sending sms messages before but because of this reason we wrote our own gsm implementation. Which I can't share I'm sorry for that. We've ported [pygsm](https://github.com/rapidsms/pygsm) and we haven't had one timeout since.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you could be right. It seems that not all devices are supported, yet. My code works fine with an old Sony-Ericsson phone. However, when I used older version of library (I think 1.14 or 1.15) with the SE device, same problem occurred, until I updated to newer library. Now I have a Siemens GSM modem and I get these errors again (using latest library version), and all the source code changes I make don't seem to help. The only thing that's confusing is that this example is working fine http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx, and the code is very, very similar to mine!

Comment: If no one else gives me a quick workaround/hint/solution to my problem, I'll have to start from scratch :( - and I'll mark this as the accepted answer...

Comment: It's probably due the incompatibility with the Siemens Modem. We use those aswell. It is weird that the codeproject thing does work. We've also seen very flaky results we had 1 where the tool worked most of the time and on 2 others it didn't work at all. Maybe it's because the codeproject-project uses .net version 1. You could maybe try to use pygsm in .net with ironpython.